Removing self-leveling concrete from wooden subfloor?
My partner and I are replacing the carpet in my office with vinyl(w/ cork underlayment) flooring. After tearing up the carpet we noticed the wooden subfloor in one corner was messed up. It's like the board they used didn't quite reach the wall so a 1"-ish piece of wood was shoved between it and the wall. This strip is level with the rest of the room, but the full board drops down maybe a 1/4" immediately, to the point laying hard flooring on top would be a mistake and eventually cause the floor to break due to void space.
We were advised to get self-leveling concrete to level it out (we got LevelQuik RS). We'd need maybe a 3-4sq' of space covered. We put the primer on with like a foot extra on both sides just in case the cement spread further, and while I was at work my partner put the cement down.
It doesn't look good. It was layered on way too thick so that corner is now higher than the rest of the room by about a half centimeter/0.2", it's spread the cover the whole 9sq'(ish) we primed instead of just where it was sunken down, and the entire concrete area is hills-and-valleys bumpy with, while not as severe as before, plenty of new smaller void spaces. I suspect the water/powder ratio was off, since the whole bag wasn't used and it only gives instructions for how much water to use with the entire 50lb bag. Also apparently the drill died while mixing and so the rest was mixed by hand.
My partner wants to try laying the floor over it but I am not optimistic. I'd rather rip it up and try again (we still have about 1/3 of the cement powder left). But, can we rip it up without ruining the subfloor? Will we need a jackhammer? The room is on the top floor, the kitchen is below it, and I'm anxious about somehow catastrophically ruining the ceiling of the kitchen or integrity of the floor. Mesh was used under it (but in some spots it pokes up through the cement). I don't want to put carpet back.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT: Photograph attempt.
https://imgur.com/a/JPTjCRN

Since it's only a few sq-ft I'd be inclined to put  a diamond cup grinding wheel on an angle grinder and 'gently' flatten it out by hand. Doing so will fill the room with dust though (and the rest of the house too if you don't seal the room off properly)...

Any chance of posting pictures? How bad is it?

Sanding and dealing with dust sounds a lot more palpable than ripping up concreate, thank you we'll look into it.
Edited main body to include a link to photos, I hope they're clear, I couldn't get across the unevenness without the plank for reference.
We did leave the (flat) baseboards in place with the plan to use quarter round to hide the gap. It's what was done on the main floor of the house and it looks fine there.
